# Cannot read data send from rust client on non anchor contract

Tags: solana-program

I'm doing unit test for my non anchor project and I'm trying to send transaction with data to contract. Here is the code:

```
#[derive(BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize)]
    struct InitState<'a> {
        variant: &'a u8,
    }
    let param_init_state = InitState {
        variant: &4,
    };
let mut transaction = Transaction::new_with_payer(
        &[Instruction::new_with_borsh(
            program_id,
            &param_init_state,
            vec![
                AccountMeta::new(payer.pubkey(), true),
                AccountMeta::new(*state_account.key, false),
                AccountMeta::new(system_program::ID, false),
            ],
        )],
        Some(&payer.pubkey()),
    );

    transaction.sign(&[&payer], recent_blockhash);

    match banks_client.process_transaction(transaction).await {
        Ok(()) => (),
        Err(e) => panic!("{}", e),
    }
```

In solana tutorial, they use try_from_slice_unchecked(input)?; to read instruction data but it does not work for me. The compiler return Custom { kind: InvalidInput, error: "Unexpected length of input" } error if I use another way:

```
#[derive(BorshDeserialize, Debug)]
struct GachaMarketplacePayload {
    nft_contract: Pubkey, // program id,
    token_id: Pubkey,     // ATA
    price: u128,
    file_name: String,
    description: String,
    cash_back: u8,
    qty: u8,
    fee: u128,
    item_id: u128,
    variant: u8,
}
        let payload = GachaMarketplacePayload::try_from_slice(input).unwrap();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The param in the instruction have to match the payload for try_from_slice

Answer (score 1):

```
 #[derive(BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize)]
 struct InitState<'a> {
     variant: &'a u8,
 }
 let param_init_state = InitState {
     variant: &4,
 };
 let mut transaction = Transaction::new_with_payer(
     &[Instruction::new_with_borsh(
         program_id,
         &param_init_state,
         vec![
             AccountMeta::new(payer.pubkey(), true),
             AccountMeta::new(*state_account.key, false),
             AccountMeta::new(system_program::ID, false),
         ],
     )],
     Some(&payer.pubkey()),
 );

 transaction.sign(&[&payer], recent_blockhash);

 match banks_client.process_transaction(transaction).await {
     Ok(()) => (),
     Err(e) => panic!("{}", e),
```

Comment: Hi @shahoria Asif Rabby, I don't understand what you mean. I see no different code from mine.